# Which nodes will be inserted into the data

Tags: elasticsearch

The elastic cluster node I built has a separate data role master role coordinate role
ingest role.
I also configured the ingest pipeline, which nodes I will pass through when I insert data. The exposed cluster link is the coordinate address

Below is my ingest pipline configuration

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/dataocean-timestamp-pipeline
{
  "description": "Adds a field to a document with the time of ingestion",
  "processors": [
    {
    "set": {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "override": false,
      "ignore_empty_value": true,
      "ignore_failure": true,
      "value": "{{_ingest.timestamp}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

coordinate to ingest to data
or other

Which nodes the correct data flows through
Does the official website have these architecture explanations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a pipeline is specified in your indexing request, then the document will first be routed to a node that has `ingest` role.

The pipeline will be executed on that node first, and then, when the document has been processed by the pipeline, it will be sent to a `data` node that hosts the shard where the document is supposed to be stored (according to its ID hash).

`master` nodes do not handle indexing requests and coordinating nodes are meant for search requests.

However, if you cluster has a single node that has all those roles, everything will happen on that node, of course.